# Syntax highlighting is almost imperceptible, especially the str class

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, syntax-highlighting

It used to highlight Lisp strings with a brown font. No longer, it seems?

```
<!-- language: lang-el -->
```

It still works with IE (11), but it no longer works with Google Chrome (version 49.0.2623.112 m or version 50.0.2661.87 m)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`<!-- language: lang-el -->` works for me. Note that the spacing is significant.

For more information about syntax highlighting, see [the FAQ on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

---

By *works*, I mean that the strings, keywords, etc. are displayed in a different color. However, I agree that the colors are hard to see, especially the string color. In Chrome, I see that strings are in `<span class="str"> and that this class has the attribute`color: #4a1c21`. On both Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04, with antialiasing on the gray background of code blocks, I can barely distinguish that color from black.

[image: magnified screenshot]

`"You nee` is in #4a1c21 string (`str`) color, `nt-prefi` is in #181a1c default (`pln`) color, but I can barely distinguish those colors. I don't know if the culprit is the choice of colors by Stack Exchange, something inherited from Google Prettify, a problem in Chrome (probably not since Firefox produces visually indistinguishable output), a problem in Linux's antialiasing (but why wouldn't it have shown up earlier?), or a bad interaction between two or more of these.

---

[Following a similar report on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321731/syntax-highlighting-for-strings-is-hard-to-see-now), the colors have now been changed. There's plenty of contrast now (at least if you aren't colorblind).

[image: post-update screenshot]

Comment: It does not work for me (but it used to). (And I had the space after the colon originally. I tried removing it, to see if that would make a difference, but it did not.)

Comment: @Drew Working for me on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21797/combine-two-directories-into-a-virtual-directory-and-bookmark-it/21799#21799 with Chrome 49.0.2623.110. Strange.

Comment: Does not work for me. I checked with two different monitors, to be sure that wasn't the problem. I reported it to Google.

Comment: But perhaps the problem is only that there is very little difference between the colors now (?). Adding a screenshot here.

Comment: @Drew The colors are present in your screenshot, but they're difficult to see, especially the string color looks almost black. This seems to be a combination of the color choice (#4a1c21) and antialiasing seems to make it particularly bad. This isn't just in Chrome, I'm getting the same antialiasing in Firefox. I don't think the colors used to be that muted, and I haven't upgraded my machines recently, so this must be an SE change.

Comment: Yes, that's what my last comment was saying. Thanks for confirming this. The colors seem to be more muted now - more similar to black.